# How do you set which widget is on top and which widget is on the bottom on 'Stack Widget' in flutter

Tags: flutter

hi guy so in my understanding of the stack widget is....

```html
Stack {
children[ child1,child2]
}//child 2 will be on top of child 1 if they widget overlap.
```

But in my code that is not the case instead child1 is on top of child2. I suspected it might be because the second child is a listview.builder.here is my code

```html
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]
    );
    var container_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var container_height = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);



    return GestureDetector(
      onDoubleTap: (){
        log("the gesture dectector went off");
        if(this.widget.changeview == true){
          setState(() {
            this.widget.changeview = false;
          });
        }
        else{
          setState(() {
            this.widget.changeview = true;
          });
        }

      },
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              DragTarget(
                builder: (
                    BuildContext context,
                    List<dynamic> accepted,
                    List<dynamic> rejected,){
                  return Center(child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                    child: Container(
                      child: FittedBox(
                        child: this.widget.onaccept_draggable,
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(),color: Colors.green),
                      width: container_width/100*90,
                      height: container_height/100 *30,
                    ),
                  ));

                },
                onAccept: (AssetImage img){
                  setState(() {
                    this.widget.onaccept_draggable = Image(image: img);
                  });
                },),
              
              
              new Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: container_width,
                    height:  (this.widget.changeview) ? container_height/2: container_height/100*30,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: 7,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          if(index == 6 ){
                            //there needs to be 1 flush in the player hands
                            return Ink.image(
                              image: AssetImage("assets/flushgame_cards/flush.png"),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              width: (this.widget.changeview) ? container_width/100*13: container_width/100*10,
                              height: (this.widget.changeview) ? container_height/2: container_height/100*20,
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          else{
                            int cards = this.widget.cards_at_my_hand[index];
                            return Draggable(
                              data: AssetImage(flush_cards_array[cards]["card_picture"]),
                              feedback: Material(
                                child: Ink.image(
                                  image: AssetImage(flush_cards_array[cards]["card_picture"]),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  width: (this.widget.changeview) ? container_width/100*13: container_width/100*10,
                                  height: (this.widget.changeview) ? container_height/2 : container_height/100*20,
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Ink.image(
                                image: AssetImage(flush_cards_array[cards]["card_picture"]),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                width: (this.widget.changeview) ? container_width/100*13: container_width/100*10,
                                height: (this.widget.changeview) ? container_height/2 : container_height/100*20,
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }

                        }),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So I tried initialising both of the widget in the initstate(){} like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165854/flutter-layout-issue-stack-z-order-not-working)

```html
initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    //I initialise the widgets here
  }
```

I also tried rearranging the widgets in different ways but still no luck. please help...

Comment: You can add position property in your particular widget under stack widget.

Comment: position property where exactly? or do you mean the 'positioned' widget use to wrap the child? if so the position widget does not specify the order it just lets you specify the padding/margin

Comment: Check this [video](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) In this video check the children widget manner and preview. You will get idea for your query.

Comment: um I not sure what you are saying or what you are saying i need to review??? the video is explaining just the basic of how stack works. This is a clearer video trying to  explain the error, since I new here and can't paste videos. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BAgws-2u6wJXS7BQiYFJGXNNPo23S3IR?usp=sharing

Comment: also one thing to note this is not the main page. When I am on the main page moving to the page where the error is happening. I get 2 error warnings.

Comment: 1) exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<dynamic, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>>#5a059):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. 
2)Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99737 pixels on the bottom.